# Gerrit Code review multiple submisions

Tags: git, gerrit

Im New to Gerrit,
trying to understand the correct way to submit multiple reviews:

i have files: a.py , b.py , c.py

i was asked to submit each file for a separate review, 
all files are on same branch but each file has its own commit

**Branch feature:**
[CommitA: a.py] -> [CommitB:b.py] -> [CommitC:c.py]

- how do i submit to Gerrit for review files b.py and c.py without Gerrit including previous files in commit chain ?
- does Gerrit know to remove already submitted files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just execute the following:

```
git push origin COMMIT-C:refs/for/BRANCH
```

Gerrit will create 3 changes (reviews), one for each commit. Change 1 will have just a.py changed, change 2 will have just b.py and change 3 will have just c.py.This is exactly what you want: each file in a separate review.

Note:

In your case, COMMIT-C depends on COMMIT-B which depends on COMMIT-A, like the following:

```
BASE --- A --- B --- C
```

If you, for example, need to fix the COMMIT-A (amend the COMMIT-A, generating COMMIT-A' and another patchset on Gerrit) you'll need to rebase COMMIT-B (generating COMMIT-B') and COMMIT-C (generating COMMIT-C'). This can be done using the "Rebase" button on the Gerrit UI.

With Gerrit the most of times is better to work the independent changes "in parallel", like the following:

```
BASE --- A
    \
     \--- B
      \
       \---C
```

This way, you can amend any change you want without the need to change the other changes too.

Comment: IMHO, the first part of the answer is VERY confusing and impractical to use. Would simply give the second part of the answer as best-practice.

Comment: Hi @Gonen, I tried to improve the answer but I was not able to change it a lot. What exactly looks confusing to you?

Comment: It is true that you can push to Gerrit 3-commits-in-a-row, as you show, but for a newbie, this is suicide, as any change to A and/or B will require a rebase of the rest of the pending commits... I feel the second method you show is the correct (and practically - the only) way to go.

Comment: It's kind of true (specially for newbies) as I said in my answer: "the most of times is better to work the independent changes "in parallel"", but it's perfectly possible to work with some commits-in-a-row if you know what you're doing and it's not so difficult to rebase the second commit using the Gerrit UI or, in the worst case, manually. I think it's important to understand what is going on and choose the best way to work instead of simply deny some procedure without fully understanding.